# Issue in putting a message into IBM Websphere MQ from "CMD"

Tags: windows, ibm-mq, aix

We are have a IBM websphere MQ[v5.2] on AIX platform and my machine is windows 7 pro which has MQ client v7.5.

I tried to connect to server remotely but i received a `Authorization` error message.  This is because my local user account does have rights to connect to queue manager remotely.

So,i created a new user account in my system with some name as on server which has rights to put/get message and now i am able to connect in client mode[Websphere MQ v7.5].

I don't know whether it is actually connecting to server but it is not giving me authorization error message so i took it as success.  But the issue is, when I tried to put message into queue from cmd using `amqsputc Queue_name mqm` the queue is opening and taking a message.  But when i tried to get the message using command `amqsgetc queue_name mqm` it says "NO MORE MESSAGE".

What could be the issue?

**Screen shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The fact the amqsputc doesnt give an error, and the fact the amqsgetc runs through to success implies the functionality is working. However, it finds nothing on the queue which makes me very suspicious that you have an application listening on that queue, which will consume the message as it arrives and hence before your amqsgetc. Check DISPLAY QSTATUS in runmqsc for IPPROCS on the queue - is it 0 when amqsgetc isnt running?

Comment: Sorry i am not having any access to server.....I can't able to login into system.

Comment: I agree with JasonE. Can you try putting messages to SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE instead of OMS_ESB_TO_CIS_WARM queue and receive from the same SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE queue? I am assuming you have enough permissions for SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE queue.

Comment: I think i don't have permission.I am getting Authorization error with code :2035 when try to put message in SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE.

Comment: Is there any other way to check this?.................Is this issue is about commit and uncommitted message on the queue?

Comment: amqsputc and amqsgetc do not use units of work (syncpoint) and hence uncommitted messages isnt the issue. You need a queue you are authorized to put to, for which nothing on the server is consuming (getting) from, and which isnt triggering an application either. Without more information its impossible to tell futher, but amqsputc and amqsgetc are pretty much the most basic functionality, and will return errors if things are fundamentally wrong